# Shrinking a Table

Tags: tables, size

I am in the process of writing up my dissertation and have fairly long regression tables meaning that I can only fit a limited space of text along with it on a page. Is there a way to move the table further up the page and well as shrink it, allowing for more explanatory text?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[margin=35mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{siunitx}                        % added
\usepackage{threeparttable}   
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}    
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalfont\large\itshape}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\footnoterule{
\kern-3\p@
\hrule\@width \textwidth
\kern2.6\p@}
\makeatother



\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}

\section{Results}\label{Results}

\subsection{Objective 1}

\begin{table}[htbp]\centering
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\caption{Investment on Bribes: Pooled Sample table\label{tab1}}
\begin{tabular*}{0.7\columnwidth}{@{\hskip\tabcolsep\extracolsep\fill}l*{1}
{D{.}{.}{-1}}}
\toprule
                &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}\\
                &\multicolumn{1}{c}{ln\_invest}\\
\midrule
Bribes&     0.008         \\
                &    (0.0136)         \\
\addlinespace
Medium(20-99)       &       0.529         \\
                &     (0.267)         \\
\addlinespace
Large(100 and over) &       2.171\sym{***}\\
                &     (0.460)         \\
\addlinespace
Government             &       0.427         \\
                &     (0.435)         \\
\addlinespace
Foreign               &      -0.337         \\
                &     (0.257)         \\
\addlinespace
Fincons            &       0.107         \\
                &     (0.154)         \\
\addlinespace
Court              &      -0.168         \\
                &     (0.148)         \\
\addlinespace
lnAge               &      0.069         \\
                &     (0.242)         \\
\addlinespace
Constant            &       9.976\sym{***}\\
                &     (0.574)         \\
                \addlinespace
 Year Dummies   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{YES}\\
        \addlinespace
        Industry Dummies & \multicolumn{1}{c}{YES}\\
        \addlinespace
        Missing Year Dummy  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{YES}\\
        \addlinespace
\midrule
Observations        &    \multicolumn{1}{c}{6417}           \\
\bottomrule
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.05\), \sym{**} \(p<0.01\), 
            \sym{***} \(p<0.001\)}\\
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{\footnotesize Note: Robust standard errors in 
parentheses, clustered by Country}\\
    \end{tabular*}
\end{table}

    The first model estimated, as shown in T, is the most basic form of the mechanism investigated. When controlling for industry and year effects, I find a positive relationship between corruption and bribery, although this result is statistically not significant. Results suggest that for a $1\%$ increase in bribe, this increases ln\_invest by 0.8 percentage points. This positive relationship contradicts our initial hypothesis of bribery
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: if you have limited space why all the `\addlinespace` to make it take extra space?  Also can you not set it as 0.107 (0.154) with the bracketed values on the same line? Finally please fix your example so people can run it and test answers, as it is it will not run and there is no indication of the available page size or if it has to fit in one or two columns, this would be much clearer if you added  a suitable (generally available) `\documentclass` and required packages

Comment: You could typeset the whole table in `\footnotesize` (it's not too uncommon).

Comment: Even after your edit there's no `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`, this is not compilable.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[margin=35mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{siunitx}                        % added
\usepackage{threeparttable}   
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}    
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalfont\large\itshape}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\footnoterule{
\kern-3\p@
\hrule\@width \textwidth
\kern2.6\p@}
\makeatother



\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}

\section{Results}\label{Results}

\subsection{Objective 1}

\begin{table}[htbp]\centering
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\caption{Investment on Bribes: Pooled Sample table\label{tab1}}
\begin{tabular*}{0.7\columnwidth}{@{\hskip\tabcolsep\extracolsep\fill}l*{2}
{D{.}{.}{-1}}}
\toprule
                \multicolumn{3}{c}{(1)}\\
                &\multicolumn{2}{c}{ln\_invest}\\
\midrule
Bribes&     0.008                  &    (0.0136)         \\
Medium(20-99)       &       0.529                  &     (0.267)         \\
Large(100 and over) &       2.171\sym{***}                &     (0.460)         \\
Government             &       0.427                  &     (0.435)         \\
Foreign               &      -0.337                  &     (0.257)         \\
Fincons            &       0.107                     &     (0.154)         \\
Court              &      -0.168                     &     (0.148)         \\
lnAge               &      0.069                     &     (0.242)         \\
Constant            &       9.976\sym{***}                &     (0.574)         \\
                \addlinespace
 Year Dummies   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{YES}\\
        Industry Dummies & \multicolumn{2}{c}{YES}\\
        Missing Year Dummy  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{YES}\\
\midrule
Observations        &    \multicolumn{1}{c}{6417}           \\
\bottomrule
        \multicolumn{3}{l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.05\), \sym{**} \(p<0.01\), 
            \sym{***} \(p<0.001\)}\\
        \multicolumn{3}{l}{\footnotesize Note: Robust standard errors in 
parentheses, clustered by Country}\\
    \end{tabular*}
\end{table}

    The first model estimated, as shown in T, is the most basic form of the mechanism investigated. When controlling for industry and year effects, I find a positive relationship between corruption and bribery, although this result is statistically not significant. Results suggest that for a $1\%$ increase in bribe, this increases ln\_invest by 0.8 percentage points. This positive relationship contradicts our initial hypothesis of bribery
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Difference to *David Carlisle* answer is that I exploit packages `threeparttable` and `siunitx`, not use any of OP definitions (they purpose are not clear to me), slightly change the definition for `\mc` which is now used in table and from preamble keep only package used in table:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=35mm]{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%\usepackage{mathtools,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs, threeparttable}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{2}{c}{#1}}% <-- changed
\usepackage{siunitx}                        

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
\begin{threeparttable}[htb]
    \caption{Investment on Bribes: Pooled Sample table}
     \label{tab1}
\sisetup{ table-space-text-pre ={(},
          table-space-text-post={\textsuperscript{***}},
          table-align-text-pre=false,
          table-align-text-post=false,
          explicit-sign,
          input-open-uncertainty={[},
          input-close-uncertainty={]}
          }
\begin{tabular*}{0.6\linewidth}{l S[table-format=-1.4] S[table-format=1.4]}
\toprule
                    &   \mc{(1)}            \\ 
                    &   \mc{ln\_invest}     \\
\midrule
Bribes              &   0.008               
                    &   (0.0136)            \\
Medium(20-99)       &   0.529               
                    &   (0.267)             \\
Large(100 and over) &   2.171\tnote{***}    
                    &   (0.460)             \\
Government          &   0.427               
                    &   (0.435)             \\
Foreign             &   -0.337              
                    &   (0.257)             \\
Fincons             &   0.107               \\
                    &   (0.154)             \\
Court               &   -0.168              
                    &   (0.148)             \\
lnAge               &   0.069               
                    &   (0.242)             \\
Constant            &   9.976\tnote{***}    
                    &   (0.574)             \\    
Year Dummies        &   \mc{YES}            \\  
Industry Dummies    &   \mc{YES}            \\
Missing Year Dummy  &   \mc{YES}            \\
\midrule
Observations        &   \mc{6417}           \\
\bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}\scriptsize\raggedright\smallskip
    \begin{tablenotes}[para, flushleft]
    \item[*]    \(p<0.1\)
    \item[**]   \(p<0.01\)
    \item[***]  \(p<0.001\)
    \end{tablenotes}
     Note: Robust standard errors in parentheses, clustered by Country
\end{threeparttable}
    \end{center}
The first model estimated, as shown in T, is the most basic form of the mechanism investigated. When controlling for industry and year effects, I find a positive relationship between corruption and bribery, although this result is statistically not significant. Results suggest that for a $1\%$ increase in bribe, this increases ln\_invest by 0.8 percentage points. This positive relationship contradicts our initial hypothesis of bribery
\end{document}
```